# What is the difference between Azure Pipelines task Gradle@3 and Gradle@2?

Tags: azure, gradle, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using `Gradle@2` to build my project in Azure DevOps. Now I have realized there is also `Gradle@3`. [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/gradle-v3?view=azure-pipelines) and even [GitHub README](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/GradleV3) are identical for both tasks.

So is there anything new in `@3`? Any reason to upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check all Azure Pipelines code here:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks

According to the [commit](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/commit/9363dd788258c33196deed3332a44bf9e3224ab7) message ("Add GradleV3 task to fix invalid demands issue") there is not different in Gradle task itself, only in [the task.json](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/9363dd788258c33196deed3332a44bf9e3224ab7/Tasks/GradleV3/task.json) that now the `demands` are empty:

```
"demands": [],
```

In Gradle@2 the `demands` are:

```
"demands": [
    "java"
]
```

Comment: In case you're right it would be really lame framework to require a new generation of task just to remove useless java agent dependency. But everything is possible with MS. I'm not going to migrate to V3 then.